tkinter and Scaling Factors on Linux
I am developing a cross-platform GUI using tkinter (for pydiode). I want the GUI to scale properly on 4K screens. Currently, it works well on macOS, but I'm having difficulty on Linux (Debian).
The first challenge is setting the size of the main window. Currently, I do this with:
root = Tk(className="diodeTransfer")
root.title("Diode Transfer")
root.minsize(width=500, height=400)

With a scaling factor of 100%, the window appears as expected, slightly wider than it is tall.

With a scaling factor of 200%, the window is too small: it is now taller than it is wide. This is because the widgets have grown in size, and 500 pixels is no longer wide enough to comfortably fit the widgets.

I think I can solve this problem by simply increasing the width and height of the application when a scaling factor >100% is used. However, I cannot find a reliable, cross-platform way to determine what scaling factor is used. Based on various suggestions online, I tried:
print(f"dpi={root.winfo_fpixels('1i')}")
print(f"scaling={root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling')}")
print(f"screen_width={root.winfo_screenwidth()}")
print(f"screen_height={root.winfo_screenheight()}")

However, I get the same output regardless of which scaling factor is used:
dpi=96.0
scaling=1.333
screen_width=3840
screen_height=2160

How can I check if a scaling factor >100% is being used, and increase the window size accordingly?

Don't know if it's a good solution but what if you call .winfo_width() on the widgets after you initialise them in another function using .after. Based on that, you can call .config(...) on the widgets that you want and change them.

How ar you increasing the scaling in the first place?

I increase scaling in the Settings app on Debian. This has the same effect as running:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2

Unfortunately, root.winfo_screenwidth() returns the same value regardless of whether the widgets have been rendered to the screen or not.

I'm not at all sure how the text size is being altered in the first place. There are, alas, many places that could be done.
You could always get the font that is being increased in size, measure the width of some text using that, and use that to determine the width and height of things in the rest of the UI. This is probably the easiest option as you can do it before making widgets.

So, checking the size of a Label? How would I check the font size?
